# How do I move an element by clicking and holding the object with the mouse?

Tags: vb.net, mousemove

I am working on a simple program which requires me to be able to select a picture box and move it to a new location by dragging it with my mouse. This is all the relevant code I have come up with currently. However, when I run the program it tries to move to where I want it to go then it seems to revert back to its previous location.

Edit: it is in a container. If this is of any relevance.

**Variables**

```
Dim startx As Integer
Dim starty As Integer
Dim endy As Integer
Dim endx As Integer
Dim finalx As Integer
Dim finaly As Integer
Dim mdown As Boolean
Dim valx As Boolean
Dim valy As Boolean
```

**Code to make image move**

```
    Private Sub picbox_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles picbox.MouseDown
        startx = MousePosition.X
        starty = MousePosition.Y
        mdown = True
        valx = False
        valy = False
    End Sub
```

`Private Sub Main_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove

End Sub

Private Sub picbox_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles picbox.MouseMove
    'Check if mouse=down
    If mdown = True Then
        endx = (MousePosition.X - Me.Left)
        endy = (MousePosition.Y - Me.Top)

        If valy = False Then
            starty = endy - sender.top
            valy = True
        End If
        If valx = False Then
            startx = endx - sender.left
            valx = True
        End If
        sender.left = endx - startx
        sender.top = endy - starty


    End If
End Sub

Private Sub picbox_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles picbox.MouseUp
    mdown = False
    valx = False
    valy = False

End Sub`

Comment: Tried your code with a simple form and just a picture box. The good news is: It works, the bad news is: I can't find where is your error.

Comment: I do have it in a layout container. Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: It's a winforms app, right? In which kind of control container you have your picturebox? In my test, without any container, directly on the client area of the form, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove it out of the container.  That is probably what is giving you the problems as your code works perfectly for me.

Comment: Holy crap, that worked. Any ideas as to why this was giving me problems?

Comment: Depends on the container but if it was a flow container of if anything was docked, that could have caused problems.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off the `Autosize` property.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
Private _isMoved As Boolean 
Private _x As Integer
Private _y As Integer

Private Sub Control_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Control.MouseDown
        _isMoved = True
        _x = e.Location.X
        _y = e.Location.Y
    End Sub

Private Sub Control_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Control.MouseMove
    If _isMoved Then
        Control.Location = New Point(Control.Location.X + (e.Location.X - _x), Control.Location.Y + (e.Location.Y - _y))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Control_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Control.MouseUp
   _isMoved = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn of AutoSize, Ensure docking of the picturebox is turned off and ensure that Anchor is Top Left